# FoxPro "command contains unrecognized phrase keyword" run time error

Tags: runtime-error, workspace, visual-foxpro

I`m new to foxpro and it`s work areas are something i don`t really don`t get so that`s likely where the problem is.

Basically i have a form that takes 2 .csv files and puts them into foxpro tables.

I get a run time error at the last line of this, can anyone see the problem?

```
web_file    = Thisform.mcFile
web_file2   = thisform.mcfile2
web_letter  = Thisform.mcLetter
web_gl      = Thisform.mcGl
web_gl2     = Thisform.mcGl2
Set Date To Dmy

Close Data

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

mcFile  = Thisform.mcFile
mcFile2 = Thisform.mcFile2

Wait Clear

If File("web_temp.dbf")
    Delete File web_temp.Dbf
Endif
Create Table web_temp (;
    email1          C(40),;
    opentime1       C(40),;
    o2idnumb1       C(10))

Use
Select 0
USE web_temp Exclusive
Append From &web_file Delim

If File("web_temp2.dbf")
    Delete File web_temp2.Dbf
Endif
Create Table web_temp2 (;
    email           C(40),;
    opentime        C(40),;
    o2idnumb        C(10))  

Use
Select 0
USE web_temp2 Exclusive

APPEND FROM &web_file2 Delim
```

Also, im not the original author, im the maintenance guy. so if things look weird its because ive been using his code without really understanding it.

Comment: I guess foxpro is too old of a language for it to be well supported here.

Anyway, in case anyone else is having trouble with this error, mine was because of the input file i was using. It was still an .csv file and looked identical in notepad to the others but i had edited it in excel and it must have screwed something up.

Copying the contents to a new file fixed everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, looks like very old code but let me try to help you understand what is going on...

```
    */ create local memory variables (web_file, web_file2, etc) from properties
    */ that exist on the form (Thisform.mcFile, Thisform.mcFile2)  No problems here
        web_file    = Thisform.mcFile
        web_file2   = thisform.mcfile2
        web_letter  = Thisform.mcLetter
        web_gl      = Thisform.mcGl
        web_gl2     = Thisform.mcGl2

*/ If doing an import of data that is "Date" based, Foxpro will expect it in
*/ Day Month Year format, but you don't appear to be doing anything with it 
*/ during your import of CSV file
        Set Date To Dmy

*/    Close database(s) that may be open
        Close Data

        * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

*/ Does the exact same as above with "web_file" and "web_file2", 
*/ so you now have two variables each with exact same values...
        mcFile  = Thisform.mcFile
        mcFile2 = Thisform.mcFile2

*/    clear the "wait" window
        Wait Clear


*/ Look to see if there is an old version of "Web_Temp.dbf", if so, 
*/ delete it and recreate it with the provided "create table" structure. 
        If File("web_temp.dbf")
            Delete File web_temp.Dbf
        Endif
        Create Table web_temp (;
            email1          C(40),;
            opentime1       C(40),;
            o2idnumb1       C(10))

*/ These three lines are not needed.  When you "CREATE TABLE", you are 
*/ explicitly STARTING the file in exclusive mode, no need to close 
*/ and re-open exclusively.
        Use
        Select 0
        USE web_temp Exclusive


*/ Take the content from the file by the name found in the variable "web_file".  
*/ This could cause a problem if the file has embedded spaces in the name... 
*/ the preferred method is to use ( parens ).  The expectation of "Delim" is 
*/ that the file is comma delimited between each expected column name
        && Append From &web_file Delim
        Append from (web_file) Delim

*/ Do the same here, but for the second file going into a second 
*/ "Temp" table for processing 
        If File("web_temp2.dbf")
            Delete File web_temp2.Dbf
        Endif
        Create Table web_temp2 (;
            email           C(40),;
            opentime        C(40),;
            o2idnumb        C(10))  

*/    Again, dont need this
        Use
        Select 0
        USE web_temp2 Exclusive

        && APPEND FROM &web_file2 Delim
        append from (web_file2) Delim
```

Now, all that said, here is some super shortcuts for you, especially if these are in fact temporary tables that you would otherwise be "discarding" when finished...

*/ The above doesn't confirm expected files exist, so I would pre-check

```
if not file( Thisform.mcFile )
   messagebox( "Sorry, the file " + Thisform.mcFile + " does not exist" )
   return
endif 

if not file( Thisform.mcFile2 )
   messagebox( "Sorry, the file " + Thisform.mcFile2 + " does not exist" )
   return
endif 

*/ In case a cursor/table is already open by the name "Web_Temp", close it
use in select( "Web_Temp" )
*/ Create a new table (temporary table that automatically 
*/ erases itself when closed when you are finished with it
create cursor Web_Temp (;
        email1          C(40),;
        opentime1       C(40),;
        o2idnumb1       C(10))

*/ Append from the file as before
append from ( Thisform.mcFile ) delim

*/ Go to another "work area" VFP allows up to 65535 different work areas, but if you
*/ ever needed that many tables open simultaneously, you have bigger problems.
select 0

*/ Same here, but for your SECOND table
use in select( "Web_Temp2" )
Create cursor web_temp2 (;
        email           C(40),;
        opentime        C(40),;
        o2idnumb        C(10))  

*/ Append from the file as before
append from ( Thisform.mcFile2 ) delim

*/ Done, continue with rest
```

If you have a file that is underlying as hex values, they'll just be pulled-in verbatim as would be seen in a notepad editor. (or via MODIFY COMMAND NameOfTheFile) from within VFP